# Is there a method to export SQL statements from a Viso 2010 professional entity-relationship diagram?

Tags: entity-relationship, visio

I have a ER diagram (10+ tables) and now want to generate sql statements.
The database menu has an option for reverse engineer, but nothing for "forward engineer" or generate sql etc..

what am i missing ? suggestion / help pls.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in "forward-engineer" functionality was dropped already at version 2003 afaik (i.e. the last Visio which had this functionality was Visio 2003 Enterprise Architect).

There is a free add-in available for 2010. You could you could give it a try:
https://forwardengineer.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have seen it, but it has many issues, corporate IT wont accept it, my system is 32 bit.. and so on.. thanks for ur suggestion.